# Firebase ".write" rule don't work as expected in simulator

Tags: firebase

I have set up my rules as they are in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

```
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is when I try to use simulator, I set auth to "Custom", then check for `$uid` in rules part.

As a result I get this:

```
Type    set
Location /foo
Data    { "key": "value" }
Auth    { "provider": "custom", "uid": "5d8a2cf9-e0b1-4332-9518-d1fb101549e2" }
Admin   false
**Write denied**
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You tried to reach /foo that's why your write is denied. You wrote your rules under /foo/$uid and not /foo. Try to reach /foo/5d8a2cf9-e0b1-4332-9518-d1fb101549e2 or change your rules under /foo (depends on what you are looking for).

Comment: @Curse thanks, added your remark as an answer! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Curse, who mentioned that I've messed up scopes of which rules should apply to resources.

Here's a solution:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      ".read": "true",  
      ".write": "true", // <-- Didn't have this before
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```